# SQLLite query has results, but when returned from the method, it loses data

Tags: ios, ios6, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a multi-threaded app that syncs data between server and ios device.

Sync happens on a separate thread. I use singleton pattern for **NSManagedObjectContext** and it is created on the main thread. I started having threading issues and upon research I saw that a context shouldn't be used outside the thread it has been initialized. So I was calling init on the context on main thread and use it in my sync thread. In order to fix that I did the following.

I created a global method that returns the **NSPersistentStoreCoordinator** and on sync thread I use this coordinator in order to create a new context. This got rid of the threading issues, but now I get some other weird behavior.

In my sync thread, I call **executeFetchRequest** method and I return the resulting array to some other method. When I debug, I see that there are 93 records and all filled with data. Then I check the array on the returned method, but even though I still get 93 records, the columns all have nil values.

Here is the code

```
+(NSArray *) GetAllRowsInTable:(NSString *) tableName
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]    initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[Globals GetPersistentStoreCoordinator]];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:tableName inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    return results;
}
```

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: Could you post the code where you create and execute the fetch request?

Comment: Is the error object set? If so, what is the error?

Comment: There is no error, but the method that calls GetAllRowsInTable method retrieves result columns as nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why this is happening. After reading on NSManagedObject, I came to the following conclusion. When ExecuteFetchRequest is called, this returns an array of faulted results which means unless valueForKey method is called on NSManagedObject, its value is not retrieved from the persistent store. Since I create the context in the method and return the results to some other method which context that the results are created doesn't exist, I get no results. All faults end up failing.